# Css nth-child ignore divs - javascript nth-child equivalent for cousin elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking for a selector that would act like the nth-child selector but that wont reset at every new div. Here's what I mean:

```css
#yellow p:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you run the preceding snippet, none of the p tags become yellow because the 3n counter in the nth-child selector 'restarts' at the second div tag. I am looking for a selector that ignores this and simply applies the css to every 3rd p element within the #yellow div (regardless of any other encapsulating tags).

Does such a selector exist, and if not what other alternatives can I use (jquery/js maybe) ?
Thanks!

Comment: are you declaring the css in the html file? or did you just copy it from the css file

Comment: yeah my bad. It should be included in the file.

Comment: Oh because the style tags are missong. But I checked and it only works if they are all together. You could use jquery instead.

Comment: how so? I am a novice at all things front-end! Thx

Comment: @this wouldn't work if you add another paragraph below the div.

Comment: the index is 0-based so adding 1 before using mod: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yellow p").each(function(i) {
    if((i+1)%3==0) $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` operate on siblings, so targeting all of the `p`'s on the page together won't work because they aren't siblings.

To target that paragraph, I would target the `div` you want and use `:nth-child()` inside of that `div` to select the `p` relative to its siblings.

```css
#yellow div:last-child p:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To do it in JS/jquery, you can just get all of the `p`'s that are a child of `#yellow` and target the 3rd one.

```js
$('#yellow p').eq(2).css('background','yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For the same reasons as I stated in the comments on @zer00ne's answer, this will work but I was hoping for something more.

Comment: @MaxSmith you can't with CSS alone. The `:nth-*` selectors work with sibling elements. You could with javascript or jquery.

Comment: How would a 'cousin :nth-* selector' work in jquery?

Comment: @MaxSmith `$('#yellow p').eq(2).css('background','yellow');`

Comment: @MaxSmith If that's the solution to your problem, then you might update the title and tags on your post. Nobody gave you a javascript solution because your post indicates you're looking for CSS, not JS. Updated my answer tho.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#yellow div:nth-of-type(2) p:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
  
  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

The easiest way is to use JavaScript / jQuery since CSS nth selectors groups are limited to basing their relationship as siblings. **Demo 2** has a plain JavaScript solution, details are commented within.

---

## CSS

Try:

> ```
> div:nth-of-type(2) p:first-of-type
> ```

This means: Select the first paragraph that has the 2nd div as it's ancestor.

### Demo 1

```css
div:nth-of-type(2) p:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2

```js
/* querySelectorAll() collects all <p> into a NodeList
|| Array.from() converts that NodeList into an array
*/
const paraList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));

// forEach() runs a function on each <p>...
paraList.forEach(function(para, idx) {

  /* Check each <p> on every iteration for their indexed 
  || position number within the array. Calculate the
  || index by dividing it by 3 and if the modulus
  || (i.e. remaining number) is 0 then set that <p>
  || background-color to yellow.
  */
  if ((idx + 1) % 3 === 0) {
    para.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="yellow">
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This should not be yellow.</p>
      <p>This should be yellow.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: granted this would work. However i was looking for a solution that applies to all p tags within #yellow. This is obviously a simplified example and to do what you suggested for the real code would be painstaking. Is there not a better solution?

Comment: @MaxSmith Every 3rd paragraph, but they are cousins? Is there a `<br/>` between every pair of divs?

Comment: the break is just there to better illustrate, it has no significance whatsoever

Comment: @MaxSmith Wouldn't matter anyways, the grouping of nth selectors are based on how they are related to each other as siblings. Each group of `<p>` siblings are only pairs not tuples. The solution is trivial if you use JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: @MaxSmith See update if your'e interested in a plain JavaScript solution.